# How do I avoid naming clashes within Python's module system?

Tags: python, django, python-module, python-import

In my Django project I have an app called `profile`, which mostly contains my `profile.models.UserProfile` class for additional information on `User` objects (may seem familiar to Django folks). Now I've put some initialization code into `profile/__init__.py` (some signals) and have ran into a problem: Django tells me that a table called `hotshot_profile` has not been found.

After literally hours of searching, I traced the problem back to importing order. Running `python -v manage.py test` I've found the following:

```
import nose.plugins.prof # precompiled from /home/rassie/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.6/site-packages/nose/plugins/prof.pyc
import hotshot # directory /usr/lib64/python2.6/hotshot
import hotshot # precompiled from /usr/lib64/python2.6/hotshot/__init__.pyc
dlopen("/home/rassie/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_hotshot.so", 2);
import _hotshot # dynamically loaded from /home/rassie/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_hotshot.so
import hotshot.stats # from /usr/lib64/python2.6/hotshot/stats.py
import profile # directory /home/rassie/MyProject/apps/profile
import profile # precompiled from /home/rassie/MyProject/apps/profile/__init__.pyc
```

So my Nose runner imports the `nose.plugins.prof` (even though this plugin is off), imports `hotshot`, which tries to import `profile`. However, `profile` gets imported from **my project**, while it ready should have been imported from system Python.

Obviously, my own `profile` module clashes with system `profile` module. I obviously can't exclude every module name that comes bundled with Python from my own programming. So the question is, where do I go from here?  Do I have to create a `myproject` namespace for all of my apps? Will Django work with that?

PS: Table's name `hotshot_profile` seems to come from a further yet-to-be-fully-analyzed naming clash with a `Profile` class from `pybb`, which I'm also using in my project. But that's out of this question's scope.

Answer (score 5):

You should never import your own modules in the form `import mymodule` (relative imports). Instead you should always use `import myproject.mymodule` instead (absolute imports). This avoids all name clashes.

Comment: I always thought I've used absolute imports by following every advice on Django I could find. It seems I need to put my apps into a namespace and then into global path and import them as you say. We'll see if that goes well :)